# R ggplot facet: varying x axis formatting and varying aesthetics by facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I was hoping someone could help with
1) varying the format of the x-axis across panels in a facet plot
2) showing the loess smoother only on the left side of the facet.

The left side is longer history, the right is last twelve months.
The real dataset has more data (more time and more variables), and so these problems become worse, but I think the below code should show my issues.
The right hand side dates are squashed, and the smoother is not needed with only twelve points.

Very grateful for any help!
Thanks
Aidan

```
    g<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(13909, 13938, 13969, 13999,
    14029, 14060, 14091, 14120, 14152, 14183, 14211, 14244, 14274,
    14302, 14334, 14364, 14393, 14425, 14456, 14487, 14517, 14547,
    14578, 14609, 14638, 14666, 14699, 14729, 14760, 14790, 14820,
    14852, 14882, 14911, 14943, 14974, 15005, 15033, 15064, 15093,
    15125, 15155, 15184, 15217, 15247, 15278, 15308, 15338, 15370,
    15399, 15429, 15460, 15125, 15155, 15184, 15217, 15247, 15278,
    15308, 15338, 15370, 15399, 15429, 15460), class = "Date"), value = c(199.8,
    195.7, 200.1, 201, 207.7, 215.1, 210.3, 202.9, 191, 186.5, 180.1,
    175.7, 164.6, 168.2, 169.9, 166.6, 174.7, 181.8, 181.3, 177.3,
    176.1, 172.2, 170, 170.7, 164.9, 164.6, 169.6, 172.3, 174.6,
    182.9, 182.1, 177.3, 171.4, 170.6, 170.2, 168.8, 157.9, 156.1,
    159.8, 161.1, 169.3, 175.6, 171.2, 171.2, 165.3, 160.8, 164,
    162.2, 154.6, 155.6, 164.8, 177.4, 169.3, 175.6, 171.2, 171.2,
    165.3, 160.8, 164, 162.2, 154.6, 155.6, 164.8, 177.4), variable = structure(c(1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NAR Median Hse Price ($000)", class = "factor"),
        var2 = c("History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "History",
        "History", "History", "History", "History", "History", "LTM",
        "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM", "LTM",
        "LTM", "LTM")), .Names = c("Date", "value", "variable", "var2"
    ), row.names = c("1016", "1017", "1018", "1019", "1020", "1021",
    "1022", "1023", "1024", "1025", "1026", "1027", "1028", "1029",
    "1030", "1031", "1032", "1033", "1034", "1035", "1036", "1037",
    "1038", "1039", "1040", "1041", "1042", "1043", "1044", "1045",
    "1046", "1047", "1048", "1049", "1050", "1051", "1052", "1053",
    "1054", "1055", "1056", "1057", "1058", "1059", "1060", "1061",
    "1062", "1063", "1064", "1065", "1066", "1067", "10561", "10571",
    "10581", "10591", "10601", "10611", "10621", "10631", "10641",
    "10651", "10661", "10671"), class = "data.frame")

    gp<-ggplot(g,aes(x=Date,y=value,group=variable)) +
         opts(
            panel.background = theme_rect(size = 1, colour = "lightgray"),
            panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
            strip.background = theme_blank(),
            axis.title.x = theme_blank(),
            axis.title.y = theme_blank()
      ,strip.text.y = theme_text(size = 12,angle = 0)
        )
    gp<- gp + geom_line(size=1)
    gp <-gp + facet_grid(variable ~ var2, scales="free")
    gp<-gp+geom_smooth(method=loess,size=1,span=.35,alpha=.005)
    gp
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your point #1 either, but you may want to investigate the `scales` and `space` arguments to `facet_grid` ...

Comment: thanks Ben. I tried experimenting with scale and space, but I couldn't seem to get slightly greater spacing or some other format change to the right side to make the dates more legible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy enough to get the smoother on one panel:

```
gp<-ggplot(g,aes(x=Date,y=value,group=variable)) +
    opts(
        panel.background = theme_rect(size = 1, colour = "lightgray"),
        panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
        strip.background = theme_blank(),
        axis.title.x = theme_blank(),
        axis.title.y = theme_blank()
        ,strip.text.y = theme_text(size = 12,angle = 0)
    )
gp<- gp + geom_line(size=1)
gp <-gp + facet_grid(variable ~ var2, scales="free")
gp<-gp+geom_smooth(data=g[g$var2=="History",],
                   method=loess,size=1,span=.35,alpha=.005)
gp
```

And as far changing the appearance of the labels on the x axis, look at the options here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/+opts()-List

Comment: on the second point, i just meant that the dates are not legible (especially after slightly more data, but even here the dates are running over each other a bit)

Comment: @Aidan, that is clear :) Try playing with the options listed here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/+opts()-List

Comment: Thanks for the link. Adding the option           axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90) makes the labels legible. Since legibility was only an issue on the right side, I was trying to think of ways to just alter the right axis. But I guess that's not easy, and altering the x axes on both sides of the grid in this way works fine. So thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I am not aware there is any way to have different options on the two axes. If it were possible I half think it would look untidy, though. I am glad this worked for you.